# Want to reload ExtJs tab panel each time it is rendered

Tags: extjs

I'm creating a set of ExtJs Panels & TabPanel in a jsp page as:

```
//left panel
var leftpanel = new Ext.Panel({
        id   :'leftpane',
        region:'west',
        width: leftPaneDefaultWidth,
        layout : 'fit',
        header : false,
        split:true
});

//right tabpanel
var rightpaneltab = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id:'rightpanetabs',
    border:false,
    enableTabScroll: true,
    region:'center'
});

//parent panel
var toppanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id : 'main',
    layout:'border',
    renderTo : 'parentDiv',
    items: [ leftpanel ,  rightpaneltab ]
});
```

Owing to a business requirement, I need to refresh/reload the contents within the ***rightpaneltab*** defined above.

Could someone pls suggest an optimal away of achieving this?

Comment: What content you need to reload ?

Comment: I have HTML contents along with Java scripts within the 'rightpaneltab'. 
To be more precise, these contents are loaded using another script that is defined with the enclosing JSP page. If there is a way to invoke that script each time the tab is rendered (in other words, if I could capture the render event somehow), even that could work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to events like `painted`, `show`, `initialize` and some others.

Check the documentation here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.tab.Panel.html#event-initialize

> `initialize` - Fires when the component has been initialized
>
> `painted` - Fires whenever this Element actually becomes visible (painted) on the screen. This is useful when you need to perform 'read' operations on the DOM element, i.e: calculating natural sizes and positioning.
>
> `show` - Fires whenever the Component is shown

Usage:

```
//left panel
var leftpanel = new Ext.Panel({
        id   :'leftpane',
        region:'west',
        width: leftPaneDefaultWidth,
        layout : 'fit',
        header : false,
        split:true
});

//right tabpanel
var rightpaneltab = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id:'rightpanetabs',
    border:false,
    enableTabScroll: true,
    region:'center',
    listeners: {
        painted: function () {
            // reload the content here
        }
    }
});

//parent panel
var toppanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id : 'main',
    layout:'border',
    renderTo : 'parentDiv',
    items: [ leftpanel ,  rightpaneltab ]
});
```